# linear least squares of matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math

Given the equation of perspective projection of a set of 3D points in an image:

```
lambda_ij * x_ij = P_i * X_j;
```

how can one estimate the values of lambda_ij matrix that minimize the above equation in least squares sense:

given that:

```
x_ij is 3 by n matrix

P_i is 3 by 4 matrix
```

and

```
X_j is 4 by n matrix.
```

I have tried

```
x_ij \ P_i * X_j
```

but this gives me a `n x n` matrix that I can't interpret, beacause I expect that lambda_ij shoud be a `1 x n` matrix.

EDIT:
 `lambda_ij .* x_ij` is element by element multiplication

Answer (score 0):

Why should `lambda_ij` be `1 x n`?  `P_i*X_j` is `3 x n`, which means `lambda_ij * x_ij` must be `3 x n`, which means `lambda_ij` must be `3 x 3`.

Matrix multiplication is not commutative, so you have to be careful about the order.  Really what you should be doing is post-multiplying both sides of the equation with `x_ij^(t)`, where `^(t)` is my bad notation of pseudoinverse.  Writing that with the MATLAB slash then becomes

```
(P_i * X_j) / x_ij
```

But, this doesn't look the right model for a perspective transform.

Comment: exactly, `lambda_ij .* x_ij` is `3 x n` and I forgot to mention that this is element by element multiplication. (if I put`lambda_ij` in the form of a `3 x n` matrix, then all elements at the same column are equal)